# Bad curve_fit result

Tags: python, scipy-optimize

I'm trying to fit data with the next custom function:

[image]

But when plotting i<sub>C</sub> and i<sub>D</sub> with the regression-adjusted constants, the results I get are as follows.

[image]

Where R<sub>S</sub>, C<sub>DL</sub>, B and E are the fitting constants from the regression.

My data is taken from a CSV with two columns, where `X` represents time and `Y` represents i<sub>T</sub>.

Here are some of the dataframe data:

```
               X         Y
903   1147.400171  0.004707
904   1148.400371  0.000036
905   1149.400371  0.110646
906   1150.400571  0.000008
907   1151.400571  0.034051
...           ...       ...
1199  1443.400764 -0.001796
1200  1444.400764 -0.001924
1201  1445.400763 -0.001779
1202  1446.400763 -0.001818
1203  1447.399963 -0.001818
```

My code to call the function looks as follows:

```py
def model_f(x, E, Rs, CDL, B):
    d = (math.pow(E/Rs, -(x/Rs*CDL))) + (B/math.sqrt(x)) + E
    return d

model_f = np.vectorize(model_f)

def get_difusive(B, t):
        return B/math.sqrt(t)

def get_capacitive(t, E,Rs,CDL):
        return math.pow((E/Rs), -(t/Rs*CDL))

                
x_data = df['X'].values
y_data = df['Y'].values

popt, pcov = curve_fit(f=model_f,xdata= x_data, ydata= y_data, p0=(1,1,1,1), bounds=(1,3))
E, Rs, CDL, B = popt

y = np.empty(len(x_data))
for i in range(len(x_data)):
    y[i] = get_difusive(B, x_data[i])
    
plt.plot(x_data, y, 'r--', label='Difusiva')

y = np.empty(len(x_data))
for i in range(len(x_data)):
    y[i] = get_capacitive(x_data[i], E, Rs, CDL)
    
plt.plot(x_data, y, 'b--', label='Capacitiva')

    
plt.plot(x_data,y_data, label='Original data')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

It is clear that the model does not fit the data correctly. I have tried to change the settings that `curve_fit` gives me and I have also tried doing a non-linear regression with other models like `lmfit`, but it hasn't worked.

Comment: I'm not sure if it will make a difference, but you can try replacing the math functions with numpy ones. You can probably get rid of `np.vectorize` if you do that. You'll also be able to perform vectorized calls to `get_difusive` and `get_capacitive`.

Comment: @jared
I just tried it, however I get the same result.

Comment: Look at the documentation for `curve_fit`. There is an option for `full_output` which you can set to `True`. More things are returned, so you'll have to adjust your code for that, but maybe that information will say why it's failing. Presumably, it's reaching the maximum number of iterations. If so, either your function is not representative of the data for a good fit or you're giving `curve_fit` a very bad starting point.

Comment: What if you use better initial guesses for the parameters?

Comment: @CarlosTorres Please share a link to the data.

Comment: @CarlosTorres Also, `x/Rs*CDL` does not match the equation in the picture. It should be `x/Rs/CDL` or `x/(Rs*CDL)`. Maybe that's your issue.

Comment: @jared
Here is a link to the entire [Dataframe in drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ECoRoSuu1E4gE2YvRHTxR854FaQlOB9U/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: @jared
I have changed the equation to x/(Rs*CDL) and it has not resulted in anything, the data still fits wrong.

Comment: You almost certainly need initial-time offsets, and your call to `pow()` is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a perfect fit, but it's a fit. Your call to `pow()` was incorrect, and you need bounds. You also need to filter away your bad data points, and subtract the initial time offset.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit


def diffusive(t: np.ndarray, t0: float, E: float, Rs: float, Cdl: float, B: float) -> np.ndarray:
    return B/np.sqrt(t - t0)  # + E


def capacitive(t: np.ndarray, t0: float, E: float, Rs: float, Cdl: float, B: float) -> np.ndarray:
    return E*(1 + np.exp(-(t - t0)/Rs/Cdl)/Rs)


def decay_model(t: np.ndarray, t0: float, E: float, Rs: float, Cdl: float, B: float) -> np.ndarray:
    i = (capacitive(t, t0, E, Rs, Cdl, B)
        + diffusive(t, t0, E, Rs, Cdl, B))
    return i


df = pd.read_csv('raw_data.csv', names=['time', 'current'], skiprows=1)
df.time -= df.time.min()
df = df[
    (df.time > 25) |
    (df.current > 2.5e-3)
].loc[1:, :]
popt, *_ = curve_fit(
    f=decay_model, xdata=df.time, ydata=df.current,
    p0=(0.1,  0.1, 1e-2, 1e2, 0),
    bounds=(
        ( 0, 1e-6, 1e-3,   1,   0),
        (10,    1,    1, 1e3,   1),
    ),
)
print(popt)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.plot(df.time, df.current, label='Original data')
ax.semilogx(df.time, diffusive(df.time, *popt), label='Diffusive fit')
ax.semilogx(df.time, capacitive(df.time, *popt), label='Capacitive fit')
ax.semilogx(df.time, decay_model(df.time, *popt), label='Total fit')

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

```
[2.00019972e+00 1.39365575e-03 4.26528691e-02 1.20252864e+02
 3.67268296e-05]
```

[image: fit]